# The Multiplication of z(x) and z(Xw) in the Quotient Polynomial from the PLONK

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

From the [PLONK paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf).

Page 29, Round 3

[image: Quotient Polynomial]

Why multiply z(x) and z(Xw) in the quotient polynomial? (why does internal wiring have to multiply input permutation)
Why the second term have to "shift by w"?

My observation is:

1. These 2 lines seem they have to cancel each other out.
2. z(x) is permutation polynomial and only about input. a(x), b(x), c(x) are about internal wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines in the quotient expression make sure $Z$ is accumulating the grand product of the inputs shifted by the identity permutation, divided by the inputs shifted by the permutation $\sigma$ describing the circuit wiring.
As described in Section 5 of the paper, this together with $Z$ starting and ending up with the value one, which is checked by the fourth line in the quotient expression, guarantee the inputs $a,b,c$ respect the correct circuit wiring.

Comment: I presume you're referring to this equation in section5: Z(a)f′(a) = g′(a)Z(a · g).  What is your identity permutation?

Comment: that equation covers both identity and sigma - referring to second line of your equation picture above when saying identity - cause beta is multiplied just by X.